# Input/output error, cannot install anything

Tags: debian, io

I have done something strange to my debian server and now I cannot install anything. It says, that locale is broken. I tried to fix it by reconfiguring dpkg, cleaning apt-get and and many other solutions from the internet. When I try to install stuff I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  xxx yyy
xx upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 27.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 19.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Fetched 27.3 MB in 19s (1,396 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 45726 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing locales (2.19-18+deb8u2) ...
dpkg: error processing package locales (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/share/locale/locale.alias': Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 locales
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
apt-get upgrade  10.60s user 2.89s system 40% cpu 32.969 total
```

I cannot remove this file due to this aforementioned error.
Trying to fix or redo locale file says, that `locales is broken or not fully installed`

As suggested in comment:

```
root@bananapi ~ # dpkg --audit
The following packages are only half installed, due to problems during
installation.  The installation can probably be completed by retrying it;
the packages can be removed using dselect or dpkg --remove:
 locales              GNU C Library: National Language (locale) data [support]
```

Tried doing it, gives me this error:

```
1 root@bananapi ~ # apt-get install locales                                                                                                                                                              :(
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,944 kB of archives.
After this operation, 395 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main locales all 2.19-18+deb8u3 [3,944 kB]
Fetched 3,944 kB in 1s (3,045 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package locales.
(Reading database ... 45727 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-18+deb8u3_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-18+deb8u3) over (2.19-18+deb8u2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-18+deb8u3_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/sbin/update-locale' before installing new version: Too many links
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-18+deb8u3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
apt-get install locales  5.53s user 1.97s system 34% cpu 21.697 total
```

Comment: Can you include the output from `dpkg --audit` [in your original question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/269034/edit)

Comment: And if you try and install locales again?  (`apt-get install locales` - what do you get?)

Comment: Update in the original post

Comment: Although to be fair, `cannot remove '/usr/share/locale/locale.alias': Input/output error` looks like that file has issues and maybe you've got filesystem corruption, can you also include the output of `ls -l /usr/share/locale/locale.alias` / `stat /usr/share/locale/locale.alias` / `file /usr/share/locale/locale.alias` and the same for `/etc/locale.alias` since I think that's where it should point.

Comment: All your commands fail due to input/output error

Comment: You might need to boot from rescue media and `fsck` your partitions.  It's looking like file corruption / filesystem corruption.

Comment: I don't think there is option of doing that. It is a single board computer, like raspberry pi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36818/discussion-between-eightbittony-and-fulaphex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to take the card out and fix it with `fsck` on another computer. Pretty simple, suggested by EightBitTony.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> cannot remove '/usr/share/locale/locale.alias': Input/output error
> ```

This is not a problem with the packaging system. The storage is corrupted. Anything that requires accessing the corrupted part of the storage fails. In this case the upgrade requires replacing a file in a corrupted directory so it fails.

Corrupted storage is a bad sign. Replace your disk and check the integrity of your data.

Comment: I had something similar on a system with a faulty SATA cable.  In my case, the kernel managed to remount the filesystem read-only, but it was still unable to do much, and syslog (and `dmesg`) were full of SATA resets.